# high order derivatives in lua?

Tags: lua, precision

I was messing around with high order derivatives on lua (i haven't tested this on any different language) and found that the lowest you set delta to the sooner it will output 0.0, look at this code and then the output
why does this happen?

```
function derivate (f, delta)
delta = delta or 1e-4
return function(x) return (f(x + delta) - f(x)) / delta end
end

c = derivate ( math.cos )
-- c is now -sinx
d = derivate (c)
-- d is now -cosx
e = derivate (d)
-- e is now sinx
f = derivate (e)
-- f is now cosx

print(math.cos(1.23 ), c(1.23) , d(1.23) , e(1.23) , f(1.23) )
```

output :

```
0.3342377271245 -0.94250551224695   -0.3341434795523    0.94257934790676    0.0
```

Comment: This code is very unstable, I tried with `delta=1E-5` and 0.0 became 11102.2; however, when `delta=1E-6` then you are right. Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences

Comment: i get the same results using 1e-5 , it outputs 11102.23 , it always creates unexpected behavior when using odd exponents, otherwise it just gives up at 0.0

Comment: try the same code with central differences such as `(f(x+delta)-f(x-delta))/(2*delta)` and now you will see even even exponents (1E-6) will become unstable

Comment: I tried your code with simple functions. After the second derivative the method becomes unstable. I am assuming in the third or 4th derivatives `delta^3` or `delta^4` causes loss of precision. This might be worth reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Comment: Every next derivative looses numeric precision.

Comment: For the record, this has nothing to do with Lua.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Yes, you are right; however, it becomes significant in the third or following derivatives.

Comment: @lhf this does have something to do with lua because lua uses 54 bit values for everything, i would imagine tho, on 64 bit doubles this would eeventually happen

Comment: @macroland a lot of that stuff is probably beyond my knowledge but ill take a look

Comment: @hec No, lhf is right. What you see here is that calculating a derivative is [*numerically unstable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_stability), which on a high level means small perturbations in input will result in large differences in output.